# Insert new row after last used row and copy formula and format from above

Tags: excel, vba

I want a macro that will find the last row with data, then insert a new row beneath and copy the format and formula from above (formula is in column F).  The code I have inserts a new row in the same spot each time.  Is this possible?

Here's what I have:

```
    Sub AddNewRow()
'
' AddNewRow Macro
'

'
    Rows("37:37").Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("F36").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F36:F37"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("F36:F37").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True _
        , AllowFiltering:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create variables to find the last and first empty rows and use that instead:

```
Sub AddNewRow()


' AddNewRow Macro

Dim LastRw As Long, EmptyRw As Long

EmptyRw = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("F:F")) + 1
LastRw = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("F:F"))

Cells(EmptyRw, 6).Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Cells(LastRw, 6).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LastRw, 6), Cells(EmptyRw, 6)), Type:=xlFillDefault
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True _
    , AllowFiltering:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use the `CurrentRegion` to find last row and fill down from there...

```
Sub AddNewRow()

ActiveSheet.Unprotect
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1).Resize(2).FillDown
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True _
    , AllowFiltering:=True

End Sub
```

Would need to change the `Range("A1")` if worksheet contents does not start in or next to cell `A1`

Comment: Thank you so much - this is so helpful!  One little hiccup I can't figure out - I have a calendar adjacent to the range that I would like to copy the conditional formatting for when the new row is inserted.  Basically the new row (with the  above code) copies everything up to H but I need it to also copy I to AM (I is a blank column with one bottom border and J-AM contain a calendar with conditional formatting).  Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can slip in a `.EntireRow` in there to fill down the whole row: `ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1).Resize(2).EntireRow.FillDown`